# Can't figure out the structure of the if/then statement for SendGrid Template using custom field

Tags: handlebars.js, sendgrid, email-templates

I have used a lot of the email marketing platforms, but I don't think I am understanding the developer guidelines for using Handlebar.js with SendGrid to use If/Then statements.

I know my way around the code, but the guide isn't clear how to structure the statement for use with their custom fields. It looks like there needs to be some sort of path. Or maybe not. The examples they use don't really help.

https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars/#basic-if-else-else-if

I've basically rewritten the code over and over and sent myself some tests. I can get the field to show up without the if-then statement, but other than that its a no go. I have also written tech support, but have not heard back yet. No chat feature :/

```
{{#if city_code=avl}}
AVL
{{else}}
not avl
{{/if}}
```

The email only contains the {{else}} part of the code. So in the above example "not avl".

Answer (score 2):

I hope you already found an answer to your question though Sendgrid does not allow to extend Handlebars with extra plug-ins contrary to suggested above.
What you need is the following construct,

```
{{#equals city_code avl}}
        AVL
{{else}}
        Not AVL
{{/equals}}
```

https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars/#conditional-statements

{{if anything}} - only check whether anything is truthy or falsy, you cannot compare it to something.

Answer (score 0):

The if statement verify only if the variable is true.

In order to achieve your example, you should create a new helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("eq", function(a, b, options){
    if (a == b) {
        return options.fn(this);
    }else{
        try{
            return options.inverse(this);
        }catch(e){}
    }
});
```

And your handlebar template will be:

```
{{#eq city_code avl}}
    AVL
{{else}}
   not avl
{{/eq}}
```

Comment: Is this something I would have to add to the email template?

Comment: you have to add it in the js that uses the template

Comment: That works. But I also found out in SendGrid, it is not possible to customize the template unless you use transactional emails.

Comment: @Greedo please could you tell me where exactly to put the helpers?

Comment: you can put the helpers in a JS that is executed before the templates (ideally, in a library file included in your templating script)